# Is it always true that $(a,b,c)(a,b,c) = (a,c,b)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I noticed that $(1,2,3)(1,2,3) = (1,3,2)$, and I also noticed that $(1,4,3)(1,4,3) = (1,3,4)$. Now, my question is whether or not it is true that for any permutation $(a,b,c)^2 = (a,c,b)$?

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter what the symbols are, the permutation treats them in the same way. This is an aspect of isomorphism which will eventually become very obvious to you, but it is good to think it through.

Comment: You're using [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation), right? I was confused for a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a purely computational answer. Since a permutation of a set is uniquely determined by its action on that set, let us consider how $(a,b,c)^2$ acts on $S$. Take $s \in S$. If $s$ is not one of $a,b,c$, then $(a,b,c)^2$ fixes $s$. Otherwise, we compute

$$a \mapsto b\mapsto c$$
$$b \mapsto c \mapsto a$$
$$c \mapsto a \mapsto b$$

so $(a,b,c)^2 = (a,c,b)$.

Answer (score 7):

This is true for 3 cycles because a 3 cycle generates a cyclic subgroup of order 3, which has only the 3 cycles $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,c,b)$, and given any nonidentity element $x$ of this subgroup, $x^2$ is the other nonidentity element. In particular, $(a,c,b)^2=(a,b,c)$.

Comment: yes , thanks a lot

Comment: @leo You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "for any cycle of length three."

The answer is yes. Just follow what happens to any element when you apply $(a,b,c)$ to it twice, and compare that with what happens to the same element when you apply $(a,c,b)$ to it once. You'll have four cases to look at: if the element is $a$, if it's $b$, if it's $c$, and if it's something that's none of those.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this is true notice that you can also see it since we know that the order of a cycle is n, so you could see it that way aswell.